# Error resolving xamarin forms dependencies when adding Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library - Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dependency-injection

I'm trying to add the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library in my xamarin forms project.

In my setup file I'm registering an AppContext type:

```
protected virtual void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // App
            builder.RegisterType<AppContext>().SingleInstance();

            RegisterViewModels(builder);

            RegisterServices(builder);

            // Persistence
            builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();

            // Xamarin
            builder.RegisterType<MessagingCenter>().As<IMessagingCenter>().SingleInstance();
        }
```

The implementation of this class is as follows:

```
private readonly IVersionService _versionService;
        private readonly IAnalyticsService _analyticsService;
        private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

        public AppContext(IVersionService versionService, IAnalyticsService analyticsService, IDialogService dialogService)
        {
            _versionService = versionService;
            _analyticsService = analyticsService;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            Task.Run(async () => await _versionService.Track()).Wait();
        }
```

The interfaces of these classes are being registered in my service container:

```
builder.RegisterType<AnalyticsService>().As<IAnalyticsService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<VersionService>().As<IVersionService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<DialogService>().As<IDialogService>().SingleInstance();
```

This works perfectly, but when I add the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library, the following error occurs when trying to resolve the AppContext:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  Message=An exception was thrown while activating Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Bootstrap.AppContext -> Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Services.General.VersionService -> Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Services.Data.AnalyticsService -> Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Persistence.UnitOfWork.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext context, System.Action`1[T] next) [0x00031] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1 (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x00079] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x0000a] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware.Execute (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext context, System.Action`1[T] next) [0x0000b] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1 (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x00079] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Execute>b__0 () [0x00000] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance (System.Guid id, System.Func`1[TResult] creator) [0x00046] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance (System.Guid primaryId, System.Nullable`1[T] qualifyingId, System.Func`1[TResult] creator) [0x00017] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext context, System.Action`1[T] next) [0x000b5] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1 (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x00079] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ScopeSelectionMiddleware.Execute (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext context, System.Action`1[T] next) [0x00093] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1 (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x00079] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext context, System.Action`1[T] next) [0x000ac] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1 (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x00079] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke (Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext ctxt) [0x0000a] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.InvokePipeline (Autofac.ResolveRequest request, Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.DefaultResolveRequestContext requestContext) [0x00006] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance (Autofac.Core.ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, Autofac.ResolveRequest request) [0x000ce] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation (Autofac.ResolveRequest request) [0x00070] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute (Autofac.ResolveRequest request) [0x00000] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent (Autofac.ResolveRequest request) [0x00039] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent (Autofac.ResolveRequest request) [0x00000] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService (Autofac.IComponentContext context, Autofac.Core.Service service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters, System.Object& instance) [0x0002e] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService (Autofac.IComponentContext context, Autofac.Core.Service service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00030] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Type serviceType, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00007] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService] (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00000] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService] (Autofac.IComponentContext context) [0x00000] in <e9b0b2d2327e4fa8a904b2f52955b19f>:0 
  at Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Bootstrap.AppContainer.Resolve[T] () [0x00001] in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\Bootstrap\AppContainer.cs:17 
  at Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.App.InitializeApplication () [0x00001] in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\App.xaml.cs:39 
  at Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.App..ctor (Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Bootstrap.AppSetup setup) [0x0001b] in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\App.xaml.cs:30 
  at Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Droid.Activities.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0007a] in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile\Ren9ve.ERP.Mobile.Android\Activities\MainActivity.cs:53 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00010] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-31/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:2791 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x00005] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:121 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

This is where the error occurs:

```
private void InitializeApplication()
        {
            Context = AppContainer.Resolve<AppContext>();
            MonkeyCache.FileStore.Barrel.ApplicationId = "ElevorMobileCache";

            SetCultureInfo();
            SetApplicationTheme();
        }
```

Comment: It tells you that it failed activating `AppContext`. Did you try to set a break point in the constructor and tried to figure out what fails to run in the ctor?